# Canopy javascript function cannot find element

Tags: javascript, f#, canopy

quite specific Canopy F# question.

I can get the url from a background image with this function with the console in chrome

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tws-article-images--preload ng-scope tws-article-images--image-small')[0].style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/['']/g, '');
```

When im trying to do the same with Canopy.

```
   let images = js "document.getElementsByClassName('tws-article-images--preload ng-scope tws-article-images--image-small')[0].style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/['']/g, '')" |> string
```

returns javascript Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Any solutions out here :)?

Comment: The `ng-scope` class indicates that the dom is rendered by angular. I don't know anything about canopy but if that js runs before the angular rendering is done the element(s) you want won't exist

Comment: @charlietfl haha yes indeed. Didn't think of that,this is correct.

Comment: My only suggestion is use a `setTimeout()` also